# Error with ./hack/local-up-cluster.sh

Tags: kubernetes

I have been trying to get my local cluster up with kubernetes. I have created the binaries and I am running the script by the name of ./hack/local-up-cluster.sh. When I run the script, I am getting this error:

```
root@ubuntu1604:~/kubernetes# ./hack/local-up-cluster.sh 
+++ [0215 00:22:00] Building go targets for linux/ppc64le:
    cmd/kube-apiserver
    cmd/kube-controller-manager
    cmd/kube-proxy
    cmd/kubectl
    cmd/kubelet
    plugin/cmd/kube-scheduler
+++ [0215 00:22:03] Placing binaries
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
API SERVER port is free, proceeding...
Detected host and ready to start services.  Doing some housekeeping first...
Using GO_OUT /root/kubernetes/_output/local/bin/linux/ppc64le
Starting services now!
Starting etcd
etcd -data-dir /tmp/tmp.5C5e2WqxLN --bind-addr 127.0.0.1:4001 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
Waiting for etcd to come up.
+++ [0215 00:22:03] On try 1, etcd: : 
{"action":"set","node":{"key":"/_test","value":"","modifiedIndex":3,"createdIndex":3}}
Waiting for apiserver to come up
!!! [0215 00:22:13] Timed out waiting for apiserver:  to answer at http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/pods; tried 10 waiting 1 between each
Cleaning up...
```

Any idea how should I debug this?

Comment: I notice that the architecture in the output is `linux/ppc64le` -- we do not support that architecture.  I'm not sure what the issue bringing the API server up is from this output -- Dimithu's suggestion is accurate re: /tmp/kube-apiserver.log -- but in order to run the kubelet you need to be on an x86_64 machine.

Comment: @PaulMorie Kubelet does run on ppc64le architecture. We have successfully built the binaries and have done the sanity testing. The reason I want a cluster up is to run tests, but I am not able to do that without doing cluster up, is there any other way to do this? I mean to run unit and integration tests?

Comment: to run unit and integration tests what you can do is: `hack/test-go.sh` (unit tests), and `hack/test-integration.sh` (integration tests)

Comment: @PaulMorie Do I need to start the cluster, before running the tests? Or can I just run it on the local build, I mean, without running the cluster?

Comment: Let me answer that in an actual answer since there is a lot of information I wish to convey :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question from the comments.  There are 4 primary types of tests in the codebase:

1. Unit tests (`hack/test-go.sh`): don't require local cluster to run; can be run while local cluster is running
2. Integration tests (`hack/test-integration.sh`): local cluster must not be running while these tests are
3. Command tests (`hack/test-cmd.sh`): local cluster must not be running while these tests are
4. E2E tests (`test/e2e/*.go`): a cluster, local or remote is required for these tests

Comment: While this answers a question from the comments it does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your api-server is not working for some reason. Check for api-server logs at /tmp/kube-apiserver.log

Comment: /tmp/kube-apiserver.log shows:
`I0412 18:27:25.330251   17561 insecure_handler.go:121] Serving insecurely on 127.0.0.1:8080
Error: failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8080: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: bind: address already in use
Usage:
  hyperkube kube-apiserver [flags]`
...

Comment: aha, changing `hack/local-up-cluster.sh` line 549 from `--insecure-port="${API_PORT}"` to `--insecure-port="8081"` allowed `local-up-cluster.sh` to bring up the cluster by avoiding the port conflict